# In Word, how can I resize a column without changing table's width?

Tags: microsoft-word

How can I manually increase column width without changing table width? [This recommendation](https://superuser.com/a/1296918/269574) didn't work. 
Please see the GIF below. 
I regret that I can't share this .docx that contains private information.

The row exhibited in the GIF lies in a long table with at least 20 rows. When I copied and pasted just this row to a new Word document, the problem vanished! I could widen Column 2.

Note  the original 'Preferred width'  in Table Properties: 6.62 cm. This looks wrong; Column 2 doesn't look 6.62 cm wide!

[image]

Comment: Please don't link to videos. Instead describe your problem so your question is self-contained. Future readers may find the video has been removed ...

Comment: There was a meta question on "video questions" earlier today... https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13072 the key problem is that, like a random website link, if that video gets taken down by you or the site owner then it could make your question difficult to understand or apply to future visitors. If people with similar problems or solutions have no way to understand or even find your question (in the case of your "image only" questions) then you are cheating yourself out of future help and cheating other users out of potential solutions. Your question should be clear and self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting column widths and row heights in Word is indeed not always easy.

Looking to your video it seems second column in your table probably has a minimum width set.

To fix it:

- Select the second column,
- right click
- "table properties"
- columns
- uncheck "preferred width"

If it doesn't work you can set desired width manually:
[image]